# How to get the id of a document in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the ID of my one of my documents using Cloud Firestore, I was trying to see if Firebase automatically adds the property ID for each element in the database but using:

```
component.id
```

I just get undefined. how can I access the id generated by firebase?

my main goal is to get the id such that I can edit the document. should I create a new table specifying and ID or does firebase already generate one?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the [minimal **complete** / standalone code with whihc any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that, it's hard to say why your `component.id` doesn't give you a document ID.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.